# Session variables on Ruby when called through a Python web service

Tags: python, ruby, session-state, web.py

I have an app running on python web.py. For a couple of data items, I contact a ruby service. I was wondering if I could, in some way, keep track of the session in ruby as well.

Every time the python calls the ruby service, it treats it as a different session.

Any help?

Thanks!

PS - This might not be trivial and I might have to pass the session variables as parameters to the ruby but I am curious. Having this will save me some time when I start refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

Usually a session cookie is used to keep track of the session between client (in your case your Python web.py part) and server (in this case the Ruby server). Make sure you save the the session cookie when in your Python part when making the first request to the Ruby service. When making a second request simple send the cookie information as well. I think Ruby will then treat as the same session.